# MagicalRecord + Core Data not finding objects between contexts despite objectID string comparison working fine

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an NSFetchedResultsController that queries on a Core Data entity, 'MyGalleryPhoto'.

I'm trying to delete some objects, and coming up against some problems. I'm using MagicalRecord. Here is my original attempt at the code, which in my view should work fine. At the point the code is run, the objects definitely exist, because they display in the fetchedResultsController.

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    for (MyGalleryPhoto *myGalleryPhoto in [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectsAtIndexes: self.selectedIndexes]) {

        NSError *error = nil;
        MyGalleryPhoto *localMyGalleryPhoto = (MyGalleryPhoto *) [localContext existingObjectWithID: myGalleryPhoto.objectID error: &error];

        NSLog(@"error: %@:%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        NSLog(@"mygp: %@", [localMyGalleryPhoto description]);

        [localMyGalleryPhoto deleteInContext: localContext];
    }

} completion:^(void){
}];
```

This code does not work. The myGalleryPhoto entry is not found and the error returned is: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133000.)" I've also tried using MR_inContext, which just calls existingObjectWithId:error:.

After a lot of messing around I've come up with this vile frankenstein's monster, that gets all the records out of the entity and compares the string representations of the ObjectIDs. This works fine. Why? I'm using a copy of MagicalRecord I downloaded from GitHub today, XCode up to date, latest SDK, et cetera.

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    NSArray *allMyGalleryPhotos = [MyGalleryPhoto findAllInContext: localContext];

    for (MyGalleryPhoto *myGalleryPhoto in [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectsAtIndexes: self.selectedIndexes]) {

        MyGalleryPhoto *myGalleryPhotoToDelete = nil;

        for (MyGalleryPhoto *existingMyGalleryPhoto in allMyGalleryPhotos) {

            NSString *existingURLString = [[existingMyGalleryPhoto.objectID URIRepresentation] absoluteString];
            NSString *URLString = [[myGalleryPhoto.objectID URIRepresentation] absoluteString];

            NSLog(@"ExistingURLString: %@", existingURLString);
            NSLog(@"URLString: %@", URLString);

            if ([URLString isEqualToString: existingURLString]) {
                myGalleryPhotoToDelete = existingMyGalleryPhoto;
            }
        }

        if (myGalleryPhotoToDelete) [myGalleryPhotoToDelete deleteInContext: localContext];

    }

} completion:^(void){
}];
```

Answer (score 5):

Cocoa Error 13000 is a Referential Integrity error, as described in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Miscellaneous/CoreData_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSManagedObjectReferentialIntegrityError). That means you're looking for an object that doesn't exist in the store. On a more practical level, that means that your contexts (I'm assuming you have more than one Managed Object Context) are not in sync. That is, you've added a new object to one context, while the other doesn't have that object because the previous context has not been saved.

Regarding your code, the first problem I see in the first example is that you are crossing thread boundaries at the very start. The fetchedResultsController has a reference to objects in another context (I'm going to assume the default context). Every time saveInBackground is called, it gives you a new context to use, but it also puts that block of code on a background thread. Crossing thread boundaries, even in the new version of Core Data, is going to give you crazy, hard to track down problems at random times.

The gist if what you're trying to do in the first (simpler) block of code is you have a collection of photo objects you want to remove from your application. I would do something like this instead:

```
NSPredicate *objectsToDelete = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self in %@", self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects];

[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *)localContext
{
     [MyGalleryPhoto deleteAllMatchingPredicate:objectsToDelete inContext:localContext];
}];
```

The deleteAllMatchingPredicate method should do a lookup of the objects in the correct context (which you weren't doing in the first block of code) so they can be deleted. It also sets up the objects to load as faults, so we're not going to load everything in memory, only to delete it immediately. It'll load only what it needs, and no more.

I would not use existingObjectWithID: in this case. This method never loads faults. Your use case means it'll load the entire object into memory, only to delete it anyway.